# Scala: Missing Records in Result

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following Scala code, which is to count the # of integers in [0, 3000000) with bit count *c*, for each possible *c*.

```
(0 until 3000000)
  .map(java.lang.Integer.bitCount)
  .groupBy(x => x)
  .map(x => (x._2.length, x._1))
  .foreach(println)
```

The code outputs everything correctly except that it fails to output the tuple corresponding to *c = 0*. See below.

```
(413512,9)
(8086,17)
......
(23,20)
(278594,8)
```

However, if I change the code by adding a filter after the `groupBy` as follows:

```
(0 until 3000000)
  .map(java.lang.Integer.bitCount)
  .groupBy(x => x)
  .filter(_._1 == 0)
  .map(x => (x._2.length, x._1))
  .foreach(println)
```

it is able to output the tuple `(1, 0)`.

**Question:** I wonder what happens here. It seems that in the first piece of code, the `map` does not enumerate over all elements in the result of `groupBy`. Is it a bug of the Scala library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the key and value the wrong way round in the new `Map`. Try:

```
(0 until 3000000)
  .map(java.lang.Integer.bitCount)
  .groupBy(x => x)
  .map(x => (x._1, x._2.length)) // First value is key
  .foreach(println)
```

This gives

```
  (0,1)
  (5,25177)
  (10,507620)
  (14,171443)
  (20,23)
  (1,22)
  (6,69632)
  (21,1)
  (9,413512)
  (13,301958)
  (2,230)
  (17,8086)
  (12,434968)
  (7,154357)
  (3,1520)
  (18,1699)
  (16,28666)
  (11,516450)
  (8,278594)
  (19,250)
  (4,7124)
  (15,78667)
```

The original failed because `(1, 0)` was replaced with `(1, 21)`